# Clean up template code

Tags: python, django

Is there a better way to do the following? Perhaps something like `if/elif/else` ?

```
{% if avail.allows_free_streaming %}Free to Stream{% endif %}
{% if avail.requires_paid_subscription %}Subscription{% endif %}
{% if not avail.requires_paid_subscription and not avail.allow_free_streaming %}N/A{% endif %}
```

Comment: Yes, Django allows use of `elif` here.

Comment: @SimeonVisser ok, could you please show how that would be done? Basically: `if allows_free_streaming: 'Free to Streaming' \ elif requires_paid_subscription: 'Subscription' \ else: 'N/A'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the following approach:

```
{% if avail.allows_free_streaming %}
    Free to Stream
{% elif avail.requires_paid_subscription %}
    Subscription
{% else %}
    N/A
{% endif %}
```